# swift prepare segue not working

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, segue

CalViewController:

```
let brain =CalculatorBrain()
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let graph = GraphController()
    graph.brain.record = brain.record
}
```

GraphViewController:

```
var brain = CalculatorBrain() {
    didSet {
        draw.variables = ["M": 1]
        let value = brain.evaluate(using: draw.variables)
        print(value)
//at that time outlet didn't set it prints the value work just fine
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var graphView: GraphView! {
    didSet {
        draw.variables = ["M": 1]
        let value = brain.evaluate(using: draw.variables)
        print(value)
//when outlet got set it not working it print nothing
 }
}
```

I just can't figure out why and how to solve this 
any idea will be appreciate

Comment: Can you go into detail: What is exactly not working, what is supposed to work. is "prepare" even being called?

Comment: @Lepidopteron already solved~ (Scott's answer)~ thanks for concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIStoryboardSegue` contains the actual view controller that you are transitioning to in its `destination property`.  Instead of passing your data to that view controller, you are passing it to a brand new view controller that you create in `prepareForSegue` (one which is promptly deleted when you leave the function).

You probably want something along the lines of:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let graph = segue.destination as? GraphController {
        graph.brain.record = brain.record
    }
}
```

I typed that without the benefit of a compiler so you may have to tweak it.